# how to pass last click item to another page using jquery

Tags: jquery

how do i pass the last clicked item to another page using jquery? I have this toggle menu in my web app. what i want to happen is when i clicked a link in my toggle menu it will go to the another page but it will retain the selected toggle menu open. Is this possible?

here's my toggle menu code for jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".product-contents").hide();
      $("div.product-header").click(function(){
         $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cookie to store its state.

There is a [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie).

Comment: great idea so long as cookies are enabled.

Comment: thanks! but then how can i use the cookie to select the element that i wish to show or open?

Comment: @nhoyti: Read the documentation linked.

Answer (score 0):

Think you're going to need to resort to plain old query strings here and get that via jQuery on the next page.